# Can't get exception if the table doesn't exits

Tags: plsql

I must kill some session that I have in a table. I'm trying to throw an exception if the table doesn't exits but I dont get the exception. Someone could help me please? These is my code:

```
DECLARE
table_not_found EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_not_found, -00942);
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (SELECT sid, serial FROM xxxxxx )
        LOOP
             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session ''' || c.sid || ',' 
                                                     || c.serial || ''' IMMEDIATE';                         
        END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
      WHEN table_not_found THEN
              dbms_output.put_line('Table not found');
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('Other');
END;
/
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You are trying to kill a session - why would you expect this to raise `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`?  There is no table involved.  An exception you might get is: `ORA-00030: User session ID does not exist`.

Comment: Well I get the sid and the serial of a table (in the for statement). Could be that these table don't exits. These is because I need to control these exception

Comment: The `sid` and `serial#` identify a **session**, not a table.   Every time a user connects to Oracle they have a session that can be seen in `v$session` view.

Comment: Yes. I know. I say that I do previously do a select to extract the sid and serial# of the v$session that I search and I put these data in a table, so I must find in a table with for

Comment: OK, so you mean that this table may not exist: `SELECT sid, serial FROM xxxxxx`?  In that case, the code will not even compile and so it will not run and you will not get a run-time exception.  I will answer now...

Comment: Thanks! Then... how could I check if the table exits?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the table `xxxxxx` does not exist then your code will not even compile and so it will not run and you will not get a run-time exception.

To make this a run-time exception you would need to select from the table using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE
table_not_found EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_not_found, -00942);
cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
v_sid INTEGER;
v_serial INTEGER;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR 'SELECT sid, serial FROM xxxxxx' ;
    LOOP
         FETCH cur INTO v_sid, v_serial;
         EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session ''' || v_sid || ',' || v_serial || ''' IMMEDIATE';
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
EXCEPTION
      WHEN table_not_found THEN
              dbms_output.put_line('Table not found');
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('Other');
END;
```